# How to move to next R line in R script

Tags: r, line, display

This is probably a really simple question. But my code continues to go out of my code editor. And I would like to let it continue to the next line. Can someone help me?

See screenshot:

[image: 1]

Comment: why not just manually break the line?

Comment: If you are using RStudio, have a look at the `code` menu - you can soft-wrap long lines, or reformat the code, for example.

Comment: What code editor are you using? It's likely to have some option for wrapping code.